# How to put a vertical space between two functions inside algorithmic environment?

Tags: spacing, algorithms

To make the algorithm readable, I would like to put some space between  two functions. E.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[t]
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Function{Euclid1}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
      \State $a\gets b$
      \State $b\gets r$
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \EndWhile
    \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
    \EndFunction

    \Function{Euclid2}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
      \State $a\gets b$
      \State $b\gets r$
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \EndWhile
    \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
    \EndFunction

  \end{algorithmic}
  \caption{Euclid2’s algorithm}\label{euclid2}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Easiest: just add an an empty `\State`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `\Statex` for an unnumbered line (or `\State` for a numbered one):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[t]
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Function{Euclid1}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
      \State $a\gets b$
      \State $b\gets r$
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \EndWhile
    \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
    \EndFunction
    \Statex
    \Function{Euclid2}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
      \State $a\gets b$
      \State $b\gets r$
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \EndWhile
    \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
    \EndFunction

  \end{algorithmic}
  \caption{Euclid2’s algorithm}\label{euclid2}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]